# TFS 2015 build agent failing to sync TFVC

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, tfvc, azure-devops

For a specific project in my TFS 2015, a vNext build agent is unable to sync source code from the repository.

Only message I can see in log file is:

> ### Starting: Get sources
>
> ---
>
> Syncing repository: RDW (TFVC)
>   Workspace Name: ws_d565d474_34;Build\1b470f52-2a65-4b67-a68a-b8c32cebcad5
>   Done syncing repository RDW to version C283662 (workspace version -1)

Note that "workspace version -1". If I check the work folder on my build agent server is empty (not even created). Still the workspace on TFS side is created (checked with TF).
I checked the permissions assigned to the account I'm running the agent on and all seems fine.

I can't find anything in the log, nor on TFS, nor on agent computer.
It is happening only for one project. I tried with a different build server but the outcome is the same.

Does anyone have any tip on what should I check in order to try to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445294/tfs-2015-build-is-not-getting-the-mapped-path/40754091#40754091).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I had the permission inheritance switched off on the folder in the source control under which all of my branches lied.
I do analyse the problem in a bit more details here http://blog.majcica.com/2015/12/24/tfs-2015-build-agent-failing-syncing-the-repository/

Answer (score 0):

The build agent service account needs to be a member of the Build Service Accounts group.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it is.