# TFS 2015 Build is not getting the Mapped path

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

For some reason my build definition are not working properly if long path mappings. If I were using the path $/Project/Samples it works OK.

My build has this in the repository tab:
[image]

Then the logs show that there is no SLN found, and I confirmed that nothing was downloaded to the agent working folders:
[image]

For me it's a bug when getting sources, as I can't see a good why it is not getting correctly the files. I already tried to add files in some folders above and it works. Some ideas?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and the logs of "Get sources" step?

Comment: There are only 4 entries in the get sources, may it be realated to long paths?

2016-07-22T21:33:19.7439002Z Syncing repository: GLB-NVS (TFVC)
 
2016-07-22T21:33:20.9638996Z Workspace Name: ws_1_11;Build\b26b6b35-d3d7-44c8-b4f1-c358c87a8356
 
2016-07-22T21:33:21.0729012Z tf get /version:C528101
 
2016-07-22T21:38:22.4865285Z Done syncing repository GLB-NVS to version C528101 (workspace version -1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"workspace version -1" usually occurs when there is no permission to access to the source control. Check the "Inheritance" settings for the folders in your source control and make sure it is set to "On". Refer to this link for details: [TFS 2015 Build Agent failing syncing the repository](http://blog.majcica.com/2015/12/24/tfs-2015-build-agent-failing-syncing-the-repository/).

Similar question here: [TFS 2015 build agent failing to sync TFVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416348/tfs-2015-build-agent-failing-to-sync-tfvc).

Comment: On the fly! It's a trick one, but it's interesting that we cannot turn off the inheritance, it was ok to turn it on here, but in some cases, it is not possible I think.

Comment: @Fabito You can turn it off, but you need to set the security permission for all the folders manually after turn it off.

Comment: I see, what is the permissions required by the build agent to download the sources?

Comment: @Fabito This depends on what will you do in the build. If you just need to get the source code, you need to set "Read" permission to "Allow" at least.

Comment: For clarification, the 1st link in the answer is to a blog about group permissions, which didn't help me because Inheritance was already turned on for the groups. I had to turn on Inheritance for the source control folders.

Answer (score 4):

This permissions issue must be addressed at both the Team Project Collection and Team Project scopes.

**First**, the Team Project Collection:

1. Browse to http://[my_tfs_server]:8080/tfs/[my_collection_name]/_admin/_security?_a=members (your Collection's Security admin tab)
2. Click on the TFS group "Project Collection Build Service Accounts"
3. Ensure the **user** (not group) "Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)" is a member of the group
4. If it is not a member, add it with the "Add Windows user or group" menu, then Browse -- you should find it in the list of users

**Second**, the Team Project:

1. Browse to http://[my_tfs_server]:8080/tfs/[my_collection_name]/[my_team_project]/_admin/_versioncontrol
2. Ensure the **user** (not group) "Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)" is present in the security list (along with the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" group)
3. If it is not a member, add it with the "Add Windows identity" menu, then Browse -- you should find it in the list of users

**Third**, ensure that the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts" group and "Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)" user have appropriate version control rights, such as Read and Label.  Make sure that Inheritance is set to On.

With these permissions in place, the -1 issue should resolve.

Comment: This is the key!

"Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)" was missing for me.  I compared to another project and was able to readd it without issue.

I had written a tool that cleared all individual permissions and turned on inheritance for all folders/files in the project.  This was inadvertently removed, it seems.  I didn't put the two together because the team in question wasn't yet consuming vNext builds, so this didn't come up until several months later, when they started transitioning to vNext.

Thanks for the help, Thomas!

Comment: Thank you I have been looking for the answer for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a long path error. A way to fix this issue is to reset the workfolder path.

> The default work folder location is a _work folder directly under the
>   agent installation directory. You can change the location to be
>   outside of the agent installation directory, for example:
>   ***/WorkFolder:C:_work*.** One reason you may want to do this is to avoid
>   "path too long" issues on the file system.
>
> [Source link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows)

And also set Clean = "false". This may also be the root cause. If you have set `/Project/Samples` and build the definition. It will pull down all files under `/project/Samples`. Set the long path again, there has been files in the working folder. TFS may not get the new files. Set **Clean= "True"** and try it again.

Comment: Seems that the issue is with the long folder path. But even adding the path as d:\w it is not getting the files yet. When I point to root folder it gets all files. If I point to get only sub folder it doesn't get anything, I tried also in different server. Created a new Team Project to replicate the issue, and it happens the same as before.