# Including content and script folders

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2018 and I have specified the source paths mapping

> $/MyFolder/MyProjectFolder 
>   /

$/MyFolder/MyProjectFolder contains a folder called Content and Scripts which are located in TFS and I want to include in the build. The folders are not included when building.

How can I include them?

Comment: Did you get source completely  for all files under Content and Scripts folder on your build agent?

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT do you mean if the tfs source files are located on the build server? Then no... Does the source need to be located on the build server?

Comment: Yes  these folders need to be pull down during the get source step in your build pipeline. They will located in  the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1\s` If there are not on the build server, definitely not included when building.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I understand now. But how can I pull down the files for content and scripts folders during the build steps?

Comment: Just saw your answer... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you have **cloaked** Content or Scripts folder or any folder which have these two subfolders in your workspace mapping.

Cloak folders will not pull down during the get source step in the build pipeline.

Then double check if your build service account have enough permission such as read/write for those folders.

You could remote to the build agent/server and manually check if those folders (Content and Scripts) are located in the build agent source directory such as 
`C:\Agent\_work\x\s\...`.

Also check the log for **get source** step in your build logs such as below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT for the suggestions. I checked and I don't have any cloaked content. The folders are missing on the build server under C:\Agent\_work\x\s\... However they are located under TFS. I don't see the files in the get source step inside the build log. It's like the get source doesn't pick up the folder from TFS. But shouldn't the get sources step pick up all files under the mapped folder?

Comment: @doorman Did you get any error or warning in the build log, double check if it's a permission related issue. To narrow down and solve a permission related issue, you should follow this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445294/tfs-2015-build-is-not-getting-the-mapped-path

Comment: @doorman Besides, if you pull some files not all the files from TFS to local. This could also be a long path error. Currently its the TFVC limitation, from `Must not contain more than 259 Unicode characters for a single folder or file name.` You have to manually tweak your file/folder structure in TFS source control to bypass this issue. From  `C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestCaseProject` to `C:\Agent\_w\1\s\TestCasePro`. More details please refer my reply in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517416/csccsc0-0-error-cs2001-source-file-file-could-not-be-found-when-runnin/47527012#47527012